# Combinational logic "IF" and "assign" statement in systemverilog

Tags: system-verilog, alu

I found a very strange behaviour when design my ALU, hope someone can have a look it and tell me what is going on.

Here is the code

```
module adder (
output logic signed[31:0] y,
output logic Cout,
input logic signed[31:0] a, b,
input logic Cin, sub
);

logic [31:0] adder_b;

assign adder_b = b ^ {32{sub}};
assign {Cout, y} = {a[31],a} + {adder_b[31],adder_b} +Cin;

endmodule

////////////////////////////////////////////////////
////////////////////////////////////////////////////
////////////////////////////////////////////////////



module andlogic (
output logic [31:0] y,
input logic [31:0] a, b
);

assign y = a & b;

endmodule



////////////////////////////////////////////////////
////////////////////////////////////////////////////
////////////////////////////////////////////////////

module orlogic (
output logic [31:0] y,
input logic [31:0] a, b
);

assign y = a | b;

endmodule

////////////////////////////////////////////////////
////////////////////////////////////////////////////
////////////////////////////////////////////////////


module xorlogic (
output logic [31:0] y,
input logic [31:0] a, b
);

assign y = a ^ b;

endmodule


///////////////////////////////////////////////////
///////////////////////////////////////////////////
///////////////////////////////////////////////////

module ALU(
output logic signed[31:0] Result,
output logic N,Z,C,V,
input logic signed[31:0] a, b,
input logic [2:0] ALU_control
);

wire [31:0] adder_rlt, and_rlt, or_rlt, xor_rlt;
logic Cin;


adder adder (
        .y (adder_rlt),
    .a (a),
    .b (b),
    .Cin (Cin),
    .Cout (Cout),
    .sub (sub)
);

andlogic andlogic (
        .y (and_rlt),
    .a (a),
    .b (b)
);

orlogic orlogic (
        .y (or_rlt),
    .a (a),
    .b (b)
);

xorlogic xorlogic (
        .y (xor_rlt),
    .a (a),
    .b (b)
);


assign C = Cout;
assign sub = ALU_control[1];
assign Cin = ALU_control[1];
assign N = Result[31];
//assign Z = (Result ==0 )? 1:0;
assign V = {{~a[31]} & {~b[31]} & Result[31]}|{a[31] & b[31] & {~Result[31]}};

always_comb
begin 

 if (Result == 0)   Z = 1;
 else   Z = 0;

 case(ALU_control)

 3'b001:  Result = adder_rlt;

 3'b010:  Result = adder_rlt;

 3'b011:  Result = and_rlt;

 3'b100:  Result = or_rlt;

 3'b101:  Result = xor_rlt;

 default: Result = 0;

 endcase

end

endmodule
```

The first 4 modules are individual functions of my ALU, the adder contains both addition and subtraction. Then here is the odd thing:

My ALU has 4 flags, Z represent Zero, it sets when the value of output `Result` is 0. If I use these code to describe the behaviour of Z

```
always_comb
begin 

 if (Result == 0)   Z = 1;
 else   Z = 0;
```

The simulation result is wrong, Z some time is 1, and some time is 0, and it looks like not depend on the value of `Result` at all.

What is more odd is the result of the synthesis result. Here the picture shows a part of my synplify synthesis result.

[image: Synthesis result]

The gate level looks like correct, Z is a AND gate of all inverted Result signals, which when Result == 0, the output Z should be 1.

However, I spend all my afternoon yesterday try to figure out how to fix this bug, I fount that if I use `assign` statement instead of using `if` statement, then the simulation gives correct behaviour. `assign Z = (Result ==0 )? 1:0;`

I thought this two version of describing Z should be same! After I modified my code by using

```
assign Z = (Result ==0 )? 1:0;
```

The synthesis result still same as the picture I showed above...

Can someone tell me what is going on?
Thanks so much!!!

Comment: Sorry for my poor English, hope my question is make sense to you guys.

Comment: In testbench, I managed to set the value of Result equal to one by add two zeros, and subtract two same magnitude variables. For the first result Z is 0, for the second result Z is 1.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I believe the issue is with your order of operation. `always_comb` blocks execute procedurally, top to bottom. In simulation, `Z` is updated first with the existing value of `Result` (from the previous time the always block was executed). The `Result` is updated and `Z` is not re-evaluated. `Result` is not part of the sensitivity list because it is a left-hand value. Therefore, `Z` will not get updated until a signal that assigns `Result` changes.

Synthesis is different, it connects equivalent logic gates which may result in asynchronous feedback. Logical equivalent is not the same as functional equivalent. This is why synthesis is giving you what you logically intend and RTL simulation is giving what you functionally wrote. Explaining the reasons for the differences is outside the scope of this question.

When coding a RTL combinational block, just do a little self check and ask yourself:

- Are the values at the end of a single pass of this always-block the intended final values? If no, rearrange your code.
- Will any current values in this always-block be used assign any values in the next pass? If yes, rearrange your code or synchronize with a flip-flop.

In ALU case, tt is an easy fix. Change:

```
always_comb begin
  if (Result==0) Z = 1;  // <-- Z is evaluated using the previous value of Result
  else Z = 0;

  /*Logic to assign Result*/ // <-- change to Result does not re-trigger the always 
end
```

To:

```
always_comb begin
  /*Logic to assign Result*/  // <-- update Result first

  if (Result==0) Z = 1; // <-- Z is evaluated using the final value of Result
  else Z = 0;
end
```

---

An alternative solution (which I ***highly discourage***) is to replace the `always_comb` with The IEEE1364-1995 style of combinational logic. Where the sensitivity list is manually defined. Here you can add `Result` to get the feed back update:

```
always @(ALU_control or adder_rlt or add_rlt or or_rtl or xor_rtl or Result)
```

I ***highly discourage*** because it easy to miss a necessary signal, unessary signals waste simulation time, creates a risk of zero time infinite loop, and you still don't get a guaranty functional equivalent between RTL and synthesis.

Comment: The `Z` assignments could also be put into a separate always block.

Comment: @Morgan, yes it can. I prefer keeping all comb loigc in the same domain in one always-block. It keeps the RTL more abstract, I've seen it give some synthesizer a little more flexibility for finding shared logic (pending other constraints), and simulators tend to give me better run-time performance. That is my experience work large designs. A separate always-block is better solution then a manual sensitivity list.

Comment: Oh my god, your answer is so great ! Thanks for you help, this help me a lot !

Comment: Worth noting that the relevant part of **IEEE Std 1800™-2012**  is **9.2.2.2.1**. `Result` isn't in the implicit sensitivity list because it falls into the second exception: "_Any expression that is also written within the block or within any function called within the block_"